# CSS Keyframes animation not working in FF 27

Tags: css, animation

I have a problem with one project. I wanted add an animated arrow by adding animated background image.

It's working in Google Chrome but not in FF.

Here's a page: http://web4u.rzeszow.pl/puppy/.

Please help.

```
        @-moz-keyframes arrow {
     0% {
       background-image: url(strzala1.png);
     }
     10% {
       background-image: url(strzala2.png);
     }
     25% {
       background-image: url(strzala3.png);
     }
     35% {
       background-image: url(strzala4.png);
     }
     45% {
       background-image: url(strzala5.png);
     }
     65% {
       background-image: url(strzala6.png);
     }
     80% {
       background-image: url(strzala7.png);
     }
     95% {
       background-image: url(strzala8.png);
     }
     100% {
       background-image: url(strzala9.png);
     }

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes "arrow" {
     0% {
       background-image: url(strzala1.png);
     }
     10% {
       background-image: url(strzala2.png);
     }
     25% {
       background-image: url(strzala3.png);
     }
     35% {
       background-image: url(strzala4.png);
     }
     45% {
       background-image: url(strzala5.png);
     }
     65% {
       background-image: url(strzala6.png);
     }
     80% {
       background-image: url(strzala7.png);
     }
     95% {
       background-image: url(strzala8.png);
     }
     100% {
       background-image: url(strzala9.png);
     }

    }


    @keyframes arrow {
     0% {
        background-image: url(strzala1.png);
     }
     10% {
        background-image: url(strzala2.png);
     }
     25% {
        background-image: url(strzala3.png);
     }
     35% {
        background-image: url(strzala4.png);
     }
     45% {
        background-image: url(strzala5.png);
     }
     65% {
        background-image: url(strzala6.png);
     }
     80% {
        background-image: url(strzala7.png);
     }
     95% {
        background-image: url(strzala8.png);
     }
     100% {
        background-image: url(strzala9.png);
     }

    }

 #strzala {
width: 185px;
height: 90px;
background-image: url(strzala.png);
position: relative;
left: 450px;
top: 60px;
-webkit-animation: arrow 3s infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: arrow 3s infinite alternate;
-ms-animation: arrow 3s infinite alternate;
animation: arrow 3s infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: you could try  multiple background and reset background-position for each step by step in your animation. it should work in FF.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to finish this project to this friday ;), now it's ok. Do you know why previous animation is not working?